# Dotted line in iText PDF cell

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to draw a dotted line in pdf line.

Dotted line is drawing fine but its drawing with lots of space at top.

I have tried to removed those spaces but unable to removed.

I have used below code to draw a dotted line ::

```
class CustomDashedLineSeparator extends DottedLineSeparator {
    protected float dash = 5;
    protected float phase = 0.5f;

    public float getDash() {
        return dash;
    }

    public float getPhase() {
        return phase;
    }

    public void setDash(float dash) {
        this.dash = dash;
    }

    public void setPhase(float phase) {
        this.phase = phase;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(PdfContentByte canvas, float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury, float y) {
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.setLineWidth(lineWidth);
        canvas.setLineDash(dash, gap, phase);
        drawLine(canvas, llx, urx, y);
        canvas.restoreState();
    }
}

    Chunk lineSeperatorChunk = getLineSeperatorCell();
    PdfPCell lineSeperatorCell = new PdfPCell();
    lineSeperatorCell.addElement(lineSeperatorChunk);

private static Chunk getLineSeperatorCell() {
    CustomDashedLineSeparator separator = new CustomDashedLineSeparator();
    separator.setDash(2);
    separator.setGap(2);
    separator.setLineWidth((float) 0.1);
    return new Chunk(separator);
}
```

I am getting output as below ::
[image]

Comment: May be this will help :http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-underline-text-dotted-line

Comment: Define *Dotted line is drawing fine but its drawing with lots of space at top.* How are you adding the dotted line? The image isn't clear. Maybe the space you see is just the margin of a page. How did you define the page? Did you define any margins?